# Loop to iterate over an array based on a pointer?

Tags: c

If I have declared an external variable like `extern char **seasons`. Any tips on how to write a loop to iterate through this array? Assuming that a NULL value is the stopping condition?

Comment: "Assuming that a NULL value is the stopping condition?" - Stopping condition of what?

Comment: Stopping for printing each element in the array

Comment: @AayushK And do you have any way of knowing the number of elements of the array?

Comment: `for(i=0; seasons[i]!=NULL; ++i) { printf("%s", seasons[i]); }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern char **seasons;

int main(){
  int i = 0;
  while(seasons[i] != NULL){
    printf(seasons[i]);
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your array look like this :

```
const char *data[] = {"This", "is", "an", "array", "of", "strings", NULL};
```

You can iterate through it like this :

```
const char** seasons = data;
int i;
for(i = 0; seasons[i] != NULL; ++i) {
    printf("%s ", seasons[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `arr` is your array and you want to stop at that index `i` were `arr` contains `NULL`, the standard `for` loop would look like this:

```
for (i = 0; arr[i]; i++)
   dostuff(arr[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's 3 variants:

```
extern char **seasons;
size_t i;
for(i = 0; seasons[i]; i++) {
   do_something(seasons[i]);
}
```

or

```
extern char **seasons;
char **i;
for(i = seasons; *i ; i++) {
   do_something(*i);
}
```

or

```
extern char **seasons;
char **i = seasons;
while(*i) {
   do_something(*i);
   i++;
}
```